# Facing issue in ssh for USB0 Interface buildroot

Tags: linux, ssh, usb, buildroot, beagleboneblack

I am working on building Custom Os using Buildroot for beaglebone black.

**Configurations:**

Linux kernel version 4.19.29

I have enabled the Dropbear for SSH.

The Script to load the drivers at boot time is:

```
#!/bin/sh

# set -e

GADGET_DIR=/config/usb_gadget/g1
OLDPWD=$(pwd)

printf "Starting USB gadget: "

modprobe cppi41
modprobe musb-am335x
modprobe musb-dsps
modprobe phy-am335x
modprobe libcomposite


mkdir /config
mount -t configfs none /config
mkdir ${GADGET_DIR}
cd ${GADGET_DIR}
echo "0x05e8" > idVendor
echo "0xa4a1" > idProduct
mkdir strings/0x409
echo "serialnumber" > strings/0x409/serialnumber
echo "manufacturer" > strings/0x409/manufacturer
echo "ECM Gadget" > strings/0x409/product
mkdir functions/ecm.usb0
mkdir configs/c.1
mkdir configs/c.1/strings/0x409
echo Conf 1 > configs/c.1/strings/0x409/configuration
echo 120 > configs/c.1/MaxPower
echo "06:32:9b:a9:9d:a5" > functions/ecm.usb0/host_addr
ln -s functions/ecm.usb0 configs/c.1
echo musb-hdrc.0 > UDC
cd ${OLDPWD}

echo "OK"
```

I have added the following in /etc/network/interfaces to assign an IP address and enable uplink for usb0 interface:

```
auto usb0
iface usb0 inet static
      address *.*.*.*
      netmask *.*.*.*
      network *.*.*.*
      gateway *.*.*.*
```

"*" represents the ipaddress ( This is just a demo example I have added the ip address in the implementation. )

My lsmod output:

```
Module                  Size  Used by    Not tainted
usb_f_ecm              16384  2
u_ether                24576  1 usb_f_ecm
libcomposite           61440 10 usb_f_ecm
phy_am335x             16384  2
phy_am335x_control     16384  1 phy_am335x
phy_generic            16384  1 phy_am335x
musb_dsps              20480  0
musb_hdrc             135168  1 musb_dsps
udc_core               53248  4 usb_f_ecm,u_ether,libcomposite,musb_hdrc
usbcore               217088  1 musb_hdrc
usb_common             16384  6 libcomposite,phy_am335x,musb_dsps,musb_hdrc,udc_core,usbcore
musb_am335x            16384  0 [permanent]
cppi41                 20480 60
```

Still, I cannot SSH using the USB Interface.

**Question:**

Am I missing any drivers or configurations required to enable SSH?

Comment: focus on the lower layers first. Does the script run? What is its output? Any errors? Is the usb0 network interface getting configured? Did you configure the USB network device on the PC you connected to via USB?

Comment: Can you provide the output of the script? Can you connect to the beaglebone black over serial? Are you able to login to buildroot over serial? If yes, what are the contents of /sys/class/udc ? Did you configure CONFIG_USB_MUSB_DUAL_ROLE to y in buildroot? Have a look at Chapter 2 from https://bootlin.com/doc/training/buildroot/buildroot-labs.pdf for reference.